# How to generate specific format id with random method in java

Tags: java, random

i want to generate a string random id in java . The id must have this pattern :

xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

i want to have :8numbers-4numbers-4numbers-4numbers-12numbers.

I want to add this symbol "-" between these numbers

```
public String randomStringId(int length) {
    String numberList = "0123456789";
    StringBuilder numberValue = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
       numberValue.append(numberList.charAt(RANDOM.nextInt(numberList.length())));
    }

     return new String(numberValue);
}
```

I tried this method, but I can't insert the "-" symbol between these values.
Example : randomStringId(32), I want this result : 8numbers-4numbers-4numbers-4numbers-12numbers.

How can i correct my function to have this result

Comment: `randomStringId(8) + "-" + randomStringId(4) + "-" ...`

Comment: Is the resulting string always supposed to be 32 chars long? What if the parameter `length` is for example 27?

Comment: Hi @Eritrean, No, the resulting string can have any value, 27, 50, 100, whatever you want.

Comment: And how should a string of 50 chars should be formatted?

Comment: Hi @Eritrean, no the string always supposed to be 32 chars long because if i specified other number long it is difficult ti be formatted.

Comment: @ln3106 Your statements are contradictory. What is your expected result? Always a sting of length 32? Then why do you need a parameter?

Comment: @Eritrean, yes always a string length 32, i doesn't need a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You need to break down into different parts and use Random from `Java.util.Random`
Then loop to generate the numbers and append - at the end, checking if we are at last part to not add it. Also it can be done by making a substring to last character after the loop.

```
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
  public static String randomStringId() {
    StringBuilder id = new StringBuilder();

    int[] parts = {8, 4, 4, 4, 12};
     for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < parts[i]; j++) {
            id.append(RANDOM.nextInt(9) + 1);
        }
        if (i!=parts.length-1) {
            id.append("-");
        }
    }
    return id.toString();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jonxag, can you explain me the code why to use 2 loop of for().

Comment: @ln3106 The first loop is iterating through the parts array that defines the structure of the random code(if you need different structure you can put it as parameter on the method) The second loop iterates x times depending on the value of the array, if parts[1]= 5 it will loop 5 times. Each time it generates one number and append it to the String

Answer (score 0):

An alternative wthout changing a lot of what you already have, could be to use a `MaskFormatter`:

```
//import java.text.ParseException;
//import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;

public static String randomStringId() throws ParseException {
    MaskFormatter mask = new MaskFormatter("########-####-####-####-############");
    mask.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);

    String numberList = "0123456789";
    StringBuilder numberValue = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        numberValue.append(numberList.charAt(new Random().nextInt(numberList.length())));
    }

    return mask.valueToString(numberValue.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Feel like a code-golf challenge :) Following is a garbage-free variant.

```java
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();
    private static final StringBuilder PATTERN = new StringBuilder("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx");
    public static synchronized String randomStringId() {
        for (int i = 0; i < PATTERN.length(); i++) {
            if (PATTERN.charAt(i) != '-') PATTERN.setCharAt(i, (char) (48 + RANDOM.nextInt(10)));
        }
        return PATTERN.toString();
    }
```

FYI 48 is ASCII for character '0'. So `48 + random(10)` gives you random chars between '0' and '9'.